# ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I am new to python and can't find any helpful information on how to fix this problem. I appreciate any help

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]
```

Error:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Elliot\Documents\python_work> & c:/Users/Elliot/Documents/python_work/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Elliot/Documents/python_work/Projects/Snake.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Elliot\Documents\python_work\Projects\Snake.py", line 2, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Users\Elliot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

I tried following other people's posts on stackflow but couldn't figure it out. Everything I read seems like another language to me and confuses me